# Core Data - NSManagedObjectContext returns nil in Master-Detail Application

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm working on a alarm clock app, for which I use the Core Data Stack from Apple's Master-Detail Application template, so everything worked fine with Core Data, until I'm calling in
`- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` a method from the MasterViewController that does some work during the app is in background and finally should the tableView `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

And from this point I always get the error

> +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'myEntity'

Everything works fine when the app is running but only when the tableView should reload when the application is in background i get this error. Anyone knows how I could solve this problem?

In AppDelegate.m

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
if (_managedObjectContext != nil) return _managedObjectContext;

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {

    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
return _managedObjectContext; }
```

I have this code in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
//some other stuff before...
WKMasterViewController *controller = (WKMasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

In my MasterViewController.m I have following code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"myEntity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"zeit" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return _fetchedResultsController; }
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**CHECK-> THIS FUNCTION**

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {}
```

**IS IT RETURNING NIL** `_managedObjectContext`?

If the variable context is nil. This means that your managedObjectContext method is not working correctly.